# Как вывести числа из массив в обратном порядке?

Tags: java

Пишу код на java. Нужно, чтобы массив выдавал мне числа в обратном порядке. Например размер массива равен 5, и `[0]=7, [1]=-9; [2]=3; [3]=25; [4]=12;`  А массив должен выдать вот так :  `[0]=12, [1]=25; [2]=3; [3]=-9; [4]=7`. Код я написал. Но почему-то он ничего не выдаёт.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] massiv = new int[5];
    massiv[0]=7;
    massiv[1]=-9;
    massiv[2]=3;
    massiv[3]=25;
    massiv[4]=12;
    int i,j,copy;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {

        for(j=4;j>=0;j--)
        {   
            copy = massiv[i];
            massiv[i]=massiv[j];
            massiv[j] = copy;
            System.out.println(massiv[i]+" "+i);
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: не помогло :///

Comment: а какая задача вообще? просто вывести задом наперед? тогда достаточно только внутреннего цикла, убрав из него строк отвечающие  за обмен и убрав `break`

Comment: А почему не написать так: `for(i = 0; i < 5 / 2; ++i){ copy = massiv[i]; massiv[i] = massiv[5-i]; massiv[5-i] = copy;}`

Comment: Правильно это делается так: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138004/1646082

Comment: не просто вывести задом наперед, нужно каждый раз заменять номер члена массива.

Comment: Адексей, ваш код только последние 2 члена сортирует , дальше не идёт

Answer (score 3):

В принципе вот.

```
int[] massiv =  {7, -9, 3, 25, 12};
int arrayLength = massiv.length;
int iterations = arrayLength / 2;

for(int i= 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
    int tmp = massiv[i];
    massiv[i] = massiv[arrayLength - 1 - i];
    massiv[arrayLength - 1 - i] = tmp;
}

// System.out.println(Arrays.toString(massiv));
```

`arrayLength / 2` - дает нам пробег только половины массива. Если он четный пробежит половину, если нечетный, например 5 символов, то итераций будет только 2, ибо целочисленное деление.

Дальше пробегаем эти итерации и меняем i-тый символ от начала массива с i-тым символом от конца. Если массив нечетный, то средний не будет ни с чем меняться.

Comment: Да, работает, но не до конца. Он мне не выводит на консоль 3,-9 и 7

Comment: Логично.... потому что **arrayLength / 2 - дает нам пробег только половины массива**. Или вы не читали текст, а сразу скопировали ответ? чтоб вывести, либо пробегаться по массиву надо и выводить, либо раскоментировать то, что закоментированно в ответе

Comment: Всё вышенаписанное было прочитано, но так как я новичок немного торможу. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

попробуй

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] massiv = new int[5];
    massiv[0]=7;
    massiv[1]=-9;
    massiv[2]=3;
    massiv[3]=25;
    massiv[4]=12;
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i=4; i >= 0; i--) {
      System.out.println("["+ counter++ + "]=" + massiv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: строку int i,j,copy; можно пропустить. не заметил ее.

Comment: [0] должен уже 12 равняться, а на примере он остается 4-ым членом

Comment: тебе нужно вывести в другом порядке или именно перевернуть массив?

Comment: вывести в другом порядке, но перевернув также и номера членов

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int massiv[] = new int[]{7,-9,3,25,12};
        int vremennyMassiv[] = new int[massiv.length];
        for(int i=0;i<massiv.length;i++)
        {
            vremennyMassiv[massiv.length-1-i]=massiv[i];//-1, потому что length=5, а индекс последнего элемента =4
        }
        massiv=vremennyMassiv;
    }
```

Для вывода можно использовать код ниже

```
for (int i : massiv)
    {
        System.out.println("[massiv]: "+i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] massiv = new int[5];
    massiv[0] = 7;
    massiv[1] = -9;
    massiv[2] = 3;
    massiv[3] = 25;
    massiv[4] = 12;

    for (int i = massiv.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
        System.out.println(massiv[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот цикл "перевернет" массив:

```
for(int i = 0; i < massiv.length / 2; i++){
    int temp = massiv[i];
    massiv[i] = massiv[massiv.length - i - 1];
    massiv[massiv.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

Этот выведет его:

```
for(int number: massiv){
    System.out.println(number);
}
```